# Echo category name in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the Text of the related products, which is at the end of the product detail page. At the moment I'm displaying **This could be interesting** by using this code

```html
<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'This could be interesting', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

What I would like to display is **Our favorite *category name***

I tried to expand the code with this snippet, without any success

```php
<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id()) ?>
```

How is it possible to get this function done?

Comment: get_the_term_list( $product_id, 'product_cat' ); - Returns the product categories in a list. - comma separated

Comment: Like this ?
`<h2><?php esc_html_e( '( $product_id, 'product_cat' );', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>`

Comment: <?php echo get_the_term_list( $product_id, 'product_cat' ); ?>

Comment: Thx Mujuonly, but that's display the subcategory and the parent category. I'm looking for the active category. 

So for example product has parent category A and subcategory B. On the product details page should be displayed the Subcategory B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little helper function that you could put in your **functions.php**

```
function get_favorite_category_title_for( $product_id ) {
    $title = __('This could be interesting', 'woocommerce');

    $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    if( count($cats) > 0 ) {
        $title = __( 'Our favorite ', 'woocommerce' ) . $cats[0]->name;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

and then replace the `h2` tag with:

`<h2><?php echo get_favorite_category_title_for( get_queried_object_id() ); ?></h2>`

you can change `get_queried_object_id` with the `$product->get_id()` if you have access to `$product` object.

Comment: Perfect Saqib, but how can i just display the current active category name?Example. Product has the parent category A and the subcategory B. It just should display the current active category. 
Another example - my breadcrumbs looks like this Home > A > B > Product. So in this case it should display B. 
Home > A > Product. In this case A

Comment: To get the deepest category replace the `wp_get_post_terms` line with `$cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array('orderby'=> 'id', 'order'=>'DESC') );` it should work.